# How to add multiple pagination in one datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I am using asp.net core with bootstrap datatable. It has one pagination for 1 datatable. I want one one more pagination , how can i add it.

Comment: You want that for all datatables in your app? Or just a specific one?

Comment: l want it for datable for specific page

Comment: A datable with extra 1 pagination on specific page

Answer (score 0):

DataTables has some built-in controls:

- `l` - length/page size dropdown
- `f` - filter / search input
- `t` - the table itself
- `i` - table information, show xxx of total entries
- `p` - pagination control

So you can always change the DataTables markup to add/remove any control you want in the `dom` option: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

For example, you can add an extra pagination on top of the current filter box in Bootstrap 4 like the following:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>" 
            + "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" 
            + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" 
            + "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
         ...
    } );
});
```

A line `<'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>` basically reads as following:

```html
<!-- < means a div -->
<!-- ` means the class assigned to the div -->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
    <!-- the pagination control -->
</div>
```